# How to run flashsim?

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, paging, flash-memory, page-replacement

I recently came across papers based on Flash Aware Page replacement Algorithm. After going through a couple of them, I have created a new algorithm by modifying a few things within the previous algorithms. I now wish to test this algorithm against other existing algorithms and need help doing the same. I came across [FlashSim](https://github.com/MatiasBjorling/flashsim) recently. I compiled it but have no idea how to run my algorithm within it. If someone could provide me step by step instructions of how to go about this, it would be great.